# button item save and button item cancel do not work in an application with core data

Tags: swift, core-data

The situation is this everything is done according to the video, for some reason it does not work, and more specifically, at the end of the video, a new object is created by clicking on and filling in all the fields, then save is pressed and the window closes and "Saving succeeded" appears in the console. When changing the situation, such a project is built without errors, but after filling out the entire form, neither cancel nor save does not work, if the forms are not filled, it throws an alert and the cancel button still does not work. All Unwind Segues are screwed on, I don’t understand why it doesn’t work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCMkv.png)

```
import UIKit

 class NewEateryTableViewController: UITableViewController, 
 UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var adresTextField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var typeTextField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var yesButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var noButton: UIButton!
         var isVisited  = false

 @IBAction func toggleIsVisitedPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == yesButton {           
 sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174,  
                                       green: 0.4862745106, 
                                       blue: 0.1411764771, 
                                       alpha: 1)
noButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, 
                                         green: 0.501960814, 
                                         blue: 0.501960814, 
                                         alpha: 1)
isVisited = true
} else {
sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544,  
                                       green: 0.1568627506, 
                                       blue: 0.07450980693, 
                                       alpha: 1)
 yesButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.501960814, 
                                           green: 0.501960814, 
                                           blue: 0.501960814, 
                                           alpha: 1)
   isVisited = false
       }
  }

 @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  if nameTextField.text == "" || adresTextField.text == "" || 
  typeTextField.text == "" {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка",           
                              message: "Ну все поля заплнены", 
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",                 
                              style: .default,           
                              handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
if let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? 
AppDelegate)?.coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext{
    let reustarant = Restaurant(context: context)
    reustarant.name = nameTextField.text
    reustarant.location = adresTextField.text
    reustarant.type = typeTextField.text
    reustarant.isVisited = isVisited
    if let image = imageView.image {
        reustarant.image = image.pngData()
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print(" Сохранение удалось ")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(" Не удалось сохранить данные\(error), \ 
              (error.userInfo)")
    }
    
    
    
  }
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueFromNewEatery", 
              sender: self)
     }
  }


override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

  yesButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, 
                                            green: 0.4862745106, 
                                            blue: 0.1411764771, 
                                            alpha: 1)
  noButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, 
                                           green: 0.1568627506, 
                                           blue: 0.07450980693, 
                                           alpha: 1)
 }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

private func imagePickerController(_picker: 
                                   UIImagePickerController,                                         
                                   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo 
info: [String : Any]) {
imageView.image = 
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage.rawValue] as? 
UIImage
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {

if indexPath.row == 0 {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Источник          
                          фотографии", message: nil, 
                                      preferredStyle: 
                                      .actionSheet)
let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Камера", style: .default, 
handler: { (action) in
self.chooseImagePickerAction(source: .camera)
})
let photoLibAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Фото", style: .default, 
handler: { (action) in
self.chooseImagePickerAction(source: .photoLibrary)
})
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Отмена", style: .cancel, 
handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
alertController.addAction(photoLibAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
 }

func chooseImagePickerAction(source: 
UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source) {
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
imagePicker.sourceType = source
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
}
```

Comment: _"does not work"_, this is something you need to explain in more detail. Do you get an error or anything printed to the console, how do you know it didn’t work etc? Without a better explanation we can’t help you

Comment: the console does not display the text "save succeeded" I'm talking about a piece of do catch code. there are no other errors in the console. I still don't know where to view the re-save result. But in the tutorial, after clicking the save button, the window closes (the window is shown in the image)

Comment: Maybe the `if` before fails, use the debugger or add a print statement(s)